# How to start a jQuery function only, when the previous execution is finished?

Tags: jquery, function, slideshow, slide, image-gallery

I'm trying to build a full width image carousel / gallery for my portfolio by myself. My first idea was to just move the whole image block `gallery_wrapper` to the left or right with a positive or negative `margin-left` *(Or do you think this is a bad idea?)*.
For both directions there is a button control which executes the jQuery function BUT if I fire the button very fast the function will again be executed while the previous one isn't finished yet which leads to wrong calculations. So I thought I could set up a variable, which I called `slide_executed`. In normal state the value would be `true`, but while the function is fired, the value is set to `false`. With a simple if statement I could check if `slide_executed` is true and only then fire the next slide.

Well, the problem is: it doesn't work. If I click to fast on the button, the slides will still be offset. What can I do?

...

So here is my HTML *(A lot of galleries I saw, were built with unordered lists. Is that actually a better way, than using nested divs?)*:

```
 <div id="gallery_wrapper">
 <div class="image" class="first active">
      <div class="image_content">
           <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000" alt="Slideshow Image 2" width="100%" style="background-color: green;" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
      <div class="image_content" style="background-color: gray;">
           <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1200/1000" alt="Slideshow Image 2" width="100%" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
      <div class="image_content">
           <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/900" alt="Slideshow Image 3" width="100%" style="background-color: blue;" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="image last">
      <div class="image_content">
           <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1100" alt="Slideshow Image 4" width="100%" />
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="overlay">
      <button class="left">Left</button>
      <button class="right">Right</button>
 </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery_wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400%; /* 100 x Anzahl der Slides */
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    direction: rtl;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%; /* 100 : Anzahl der Slides */
    float: left;
}

.image_content {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.overlay {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 20;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay button {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Yeah and this one is my jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var slide_width = +$('.image_content').outerWidth();
var slide_executed = true;

var slide_right = function () {
    slide_executed = false;
    console.log(slide_executed);
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left')) - slide_width;
    $('#gallery_wrapper').animate({
        'margin-left': left_indent
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
    slide_executed = true;
    console.log(slide_executed);
};

var slide_left = function () {
    slide_executed = false;
    console.log(slide_executed);
    var right_indent = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left')) + slide_width;
    $('#gallery_wrapper').animate({
        'margin-left': right_indent
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
    slide_executed = true;
    console.log(slide_executed);
};

$('.left').click(function () {
    if (slide_executed == true) {
        slide_left();
    };
});

$('.right').click(function () {
    if (slide_executed == true) {
        slide_right();
    };
});

});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucctqo5d/) of the whole thing…

Comment: Oh ok. I thought this would make the code reusable…

Comment: It's not necessary to store the functions in a variable. Here, have a look at this: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ucctqo5d/4/). Unless you're planning on calling those functions from more places, this doesn't change reusability. (Sorry for posting this again, you probably already read it under Krzysiek's answer, but he wouldn't stop whining about the comment not being allowed under his answer, even though it's based on his code, so...)

Comment: I was planning to reuse it for an arrow key and touch swipe control and thought it would be better to write a global function. Is that right? Alert: noob question…

Comment: Ah, okay yeah, then a global function is the way to go. I had another look at your code, and I made it even shorter: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ucctqo5d/7/), whilst being global. (I moved the if-clause inside the slide-function, and reduced the two functions to one. You now pass along the direction as a variable `-1`/`1` when you call the function)

Comment: Ha! ― that's very nice, man!

Comment: @myfunkyside Now I was trying to implement the dragging thing and a new question occured: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357062/how-to-execute-a-jquery-function-when-dragging-an-image-on-the-x-axis If you are interested :D

Comment: sure, I'll have a look:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should disable controls.

```
$('.left').click(function () {
    if (!$('#gallery_wrapper').is(':animated')) {
        slide_left();
    };
});

$('.right').click(function () {
    if (!$('#gallery_wrapper').is(':animated')) {
        slide_right();
    };
});
```

`$().animation` is non-blocking function, so even animation is not complete `slide_executed` will be set to `true`

Comment: Could you pls explain your last sentence a bit more. do you mean "if animation is not complete `slide_executed` will be set to `true"?

Comment: Animation is created using `setInterval` (but not always) which is asynchronous. `$().animate()` is something like: run function (frame) every 7ms until animation will be completed, but before this 7ms do your work and don't care about me. I couldn't be more clear ;)

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Thank you again for that perfect solution plus your explanation… :)