# How to execute a jQuery function when dragging an image on the x-axis?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, image-gallery

I tried to make my image carousel draggable, so I added the `draggable` component from jQuery UI and detected wether the user is dragging left or right. Sadly this already destroyed my old button controls which don't work anymore. After that I've added an if-elseif-statement which was supposed to perform the slide either to the right or to the left. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var slide = function (dir) {
    if (!$('#gallery_wrapper').is(':animated')) {
        var indent = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left')) - ($('.image_content').outerWidth() * dir);
        $('#gallery_wrapper').animate({
            'margin-left': indent
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    }
};

$('.left').click(function () {
    slide(-1);
});
$('.right').click(function () {
    slide(1);
});

$(".image").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        this.previousPosition = ui.position;
    },
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var direction = (this.previousPosition.left > ui.position.left) ? 'left' : 'right';
        if (direction == 'left') {
            slide(-1);
        } else if (direction == 'right') {
            slide(1);
        };

    });

});
```

Here the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o35Ldxke/).

*Maybe I just should use Dragdealer…*

Comment: I get two console errors in your jsfiddle, check them out

Comment: @devqon I only got one. Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/o35Ldxke/3/

Comment: When adding a jsfiddle, please make sure that the code is free of syntax errors, otherwise no part of the code will run. You are missing a `});` at the end (the one that belongs to the `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Answer (score 2):

**Code Snippet  (JS, CSS, HTML):**

```js
$(window).on('load',function() {
//SLIDE----------------------------------------
  var slide = function(direction, distance){
    if (!$('#gallery_wrapper').is(':animated')) {
      var indent = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left')) - ($('.image div').outerWidth() * direction) - distance; //'distance' re-corrects for the distance-correction in $('.image').draggable({stop})

      $('#gallery_wrapper').animate({
        'margin-left': indent
      },{
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
      });
    }
  };

//SLIDE-HANDLERS-------------------------------
  $('.left').click(function() {slide(-1,0);}); //direction, distance
  $('.right').click(function() {slide(1,0);}); //direction, distance
  $('.image').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      this.previousPosition = ui.position;
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).css('left','0'); //reset image's position after drag

      var distance = ui.position.left - this.previousPosition.left;
      //only slide if there is a next or previous image to slide to
      if (!(($(this).hasClass('first')&&distance>=0) || ($(this).hasClass('last')&&distance<0))) {
        $('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left','+='+distance); //correct for image's drag distance
        slide((distance<0)?1:-1, distance); //direction, distance
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery_wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400%;
  /* 100 x Anzahl der Slides */
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  direction: rtl;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  /* 100 : Anzahl der Slides */
  float: left;
}
.image div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.image svg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.overlay {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 20;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.overlay button {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 20;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="gallery_wrapper">
  <div class="image first active">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000" alt="Slideshow Image 2" style="background-color: green;" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div style="background-color:gray;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1200/1000" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/900" alt="Slideshow Image 3" style="background-color: blue;" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="image last">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1100" alt="Slideshow Image 4" /></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay">
  <button class="left">Left</button>
  <button class="right">Right</button>
</div>
```

**(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o35Ldxke/19/)**

Comments in the code explain how it works.

---

Besides the changes in the JS code, I made some changes in your HTML (and CSS) as well:

- `'.image_content'` class removed, I use `'.image div'` instead (also in CSS)
- `style="width:100%;"` removed in `<img>`, I moved it to CSS
- your first `'.image'` div had two class-tags, I moved everything into one tag

So your basic image element-block looks like this now:

```
<div class="image">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/900" alt="Slideshow Image 1" /></div>
</div>
```